# Unable to start receiver (Activity Not Found)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, development-environment

I developed an application and put that on app store. Afterwords i wanted to change the package name so i just changed the application ID in build.gradle so that it looks appropriate in link. I didn't change anything else not the package name, not the manifest file etc. Application worked fine but now it's showing an error of **ActivityNotFound exception** on the launcher activity which is called through a broadcast receiver although that activity is defined in manifest file. May i know where am i wrong at?
This is the manifest file coding:

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<activity
android:name=".BatteryChargerFast"
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:launchMode="singleTask">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And below is the coding of broadcast Receiver:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String TAG="PowerConnectionReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("packagename", 
"packagename.BatteryChargerFast");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("fast", true);
context.startActivity(i);
}
}
```

the error states:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   packagename.PowerConnectionReceiver:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {packagename/packagename.BatteryChargerFast}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Because when you change applicationId in gradle, it overrides the Manifest's id. I am not sure but you should try the following to see if it works
: i.setClassName("YourNewApplicationId", 
"packagename.BatteryChargerFast");
or
: i.setClassName("YourNewApplicationId", 
"YourNewApplicationId.BatteryChargerFast");

Comment: @sam_0829 alright let me edit this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change applicationId in gradle, it overrides the Manifest's id.
so you need to change your code from:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("packagename", 
"packagename.BatteryChargerFast");
```

To:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("your.new.app.id", 
    "packagename.BatteryChargerFast");
```

or may be even simpler where you don't need to consider all this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), BatteryChargerFast.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("fast", true);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```